# Anonymous function in condition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to use an anonymous function in the condition of an if-statement

Using Firefox 60.7.2.esr running JS 1.5

I tried something like this, figuring it should work like the anonymous function in a forEach statement:

```js
if (function() {
    var b = true;
    if (b) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}) {
    //do something 
}
```

My actual anonymous function is quite a bit more elaborate, but in principle it should work the same way. The problem seems to be that the anonymous function does not run at all. Is there a way to make it run?

Comment: [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need ot use an  [IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) in this case:

```js
if ( (function(){ var b = true; if (b) { return true; } else { return false; } })() )
{
    //do something 
    console.log("Doing something...");
}
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

However, the code will be too hard to read (IMO), would be better to do something like this:

```js
function checkForDoSomething()
{
    var b = true;

    if (b)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

if ( checkForDoSomething() )
{
    //do something 
    console.log("Doing something...");
}
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Thank you. IIFE is precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

All you're doing is declaring a function here, it's never actually invoked. Why not just clean up the code a bit, and make it more readable:

```js
const fn = function() {
    var b = true;
    if (b) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

if ( fn() ) {
    //do something
    console.log('fn() is true!')
}
```

Ultimately, to call your function, you need to invoke the function by using `()`, and optionally passing it parameters. If you want to keep the ugly mess you have there, simply wrap the function in () so you don't get syntax errors, and then directly afterwards invoke it:

```
if ( (function() {
    var b = true;
    if (b) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
})() ) {
    //do something 
}
```

Comment: Because then it would not be an anonymous function. I am trying to ascertain whether what I asked about is an option, but I do understand that I could use either a named function or incorporate the anonymous function's code into the ordinary code sequence, the latter being how my code is currently formulated.

Comment: See my second part of the answer, or IIFE guide, on the numerous ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work as expected, add parenthesis `( )` around the definition of your anonymous function and then after the closing parenthesis, add `()` to cause the anonymous function to be invoked:

```js
if ((function() {
    var b = true;
    if (b) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
})()) {
    console.log('if passed');
}
```